# Golf the repeated totient function

Tags: code-golf, number-theory

You will take two positive integers `n` and `x` as input, and output [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) (number of positive integers less than `x` co-prime to `x`) applied `n` times.

## Testcases

```
n x   result
1 10  4
2 10  2
3 10  1
1 100 40
2 100 16
3 100 8
4 100 4
5 100 2
6 100 1
```

Comment: [Extremely closely related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/63710/194), [almost as closely related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/67773/194).

Comment: You know, people who does not use the proper name (totient) makes it hard to find.

Comment: I found both of those by searching for *totient*

Comment: @PeterTaylor I see. I only searched the question.

Comment: 1) The repeated application is completely unnecessary for this challenge, 2) That's a sigma, not a phi, right?

Comment: @Sp3000 Oops... let's assume that it is a phi, lol.

Comment: His avatar is actually the [sum of divisors function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Definition) - [OEIS sequence A000203](https://oeis.org/A000203)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

Code:

```
FÕ
```

Explanation:

```
F   # Do the following n times:
 Õ  #   ..Calculate the totient
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RsOV&input=MQoxMDA).

Comment: You beat me by 30 seconds. Should have done the explanation faster :P

Comment: @Emigna First post a minimal answer, then add the explanation :-)

Comment: We have a winner here...

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <s>84</s> <s>78</s> 70 bytes

```python
n,x=input();exec('k=m=1;'+'x-=(x%k<m%k)*x/k;m*=k*k;k+=1;'*x)*n;print x
```

*Thanks to @xnor for golfing off 8 bytes!*

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/qVLteW).

#### Background

By [Euler's product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler.27s_product_formula),

[image: Euler's product formula]

where **φ** denotes Euler's totient function and **p** varies only over prime numbers.

To identify primes, we use a corollary of [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem):

[image: corollary of Wilson's theorem]

#### How it works

After reading the input, we construct and execute a certain string. The executed code is roughly equivalent to the following.

```python
r = range(x)
for _ in range(n):
    k = 1
    m = 1
    for _ in r:
        x -= (x % k < m % k) * x / k
        m *= k**2
        k += 1
```

The inner loop will set **x = φ(x)**, so executing it **n** times stores the desired output in **x**.

At all times, the variable **m** will be equal to the square of the factorial of **k - 1**. In fact, we set **k = 1** and **m = 0!<sup>2</sup> = 1** at the beginning of the inner loop.

**k** varies from its initial value **1** to the initial value of **x** and is incremented each time the sinner loop is executed. **m** is updated accordingly by multiplying it by the "old" value of **k<sup>2</sup>**.

For the actual calculation of **x**, recall that `m%k` will yield **1** if **m** is prime and **0** if not. This means that `x%k<m%k` will yield **True** if and only if both **k** is a prime number and **x** is divisible by **k**.

In this case, `(x%k<m%k)*x/k` yields **x / k**, and subtracting it from **x** replaces its previous value with **x(1 - 1/k)**, as in Euler's product formula. Otherwise, `(x%k<m%k)*x/k` yields **0** and **x** remains unchanged.

Comment: That nested string execution looks neat... do you mind adding an explanation?

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Another beautiful mathematical solution! It looks like you can do `x-=x/k*(x%k<m%k)` for `x=[x,x/k*~-k][x%k<m%k]`.

Comment: The `exec` should work as `exec("..."+"..."*x)*n`, since there's no harm in using the too-high initial `x` as the count for each inner loop.

Comment: @xnor That's very clever and saved a lot of bytes. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

### Actually, 4 bytes

```
`▒`n
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=YOKWkmBu&input=MTAwCjI)

This program takes `x` as the first input, and `n` as the second input.

Explanation:

```
`▒`n
`▒`n  call the following function n times:
 ▒      totient(x)
```

Comment: This messes with my brain ▒_▒

Comment: Is this actually 4 bytes? >_>

Comment: @Geobits You're seriously very funny.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
:"_Zp
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OiJfWnA&input=MgoxMDAKCg)

```
:        % Take n implicitly. Generate vector [1 2 ... n]
"        % For each loop, that is, repeat n times
  _Zp    %   Euler's totient function. Takes x implicitly first time
         % End for. Display implicitly
```

---

Without using Euler's totient function: **9 bytes**

```
:"t:Zd1=s
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OiJ0OlpkMT1z&input=MgoxMDAKCg)

```
:        % Take n implicitly. Generate range [1 2 ... n]
"        % For each loop, that is, repeat n times
  t      %   Duplicate. Takes x implicitly first time. Call that t
  :      %   Range [1 2 ... t]
  Zd     %   GCD of t and [1 2 ... t], elementwise
  1=s    %   How many times the result equals 1: Euler's totient
         % End for. Display implicitly
```

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, 17 bytes

```
EulerPhi~Nest~##&
```

An unnamed function which takes `x` as the first argument and `n` as the second. Here `EulerPhi~Nest~##` is short for `Nest[EulerPhi, ##]` and then `##` expands to a sequence of both arguments so we get `Nest[EulerPhi, x, n]`. And `EulerPhi` is of course the totient function.

Answer (score 3):

### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ÆṪ¡
```

Expects `x` as the first argument and `n` as the second.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w4bhuarCoQ&input=&args=MTAw+Mg)

This is as straightforward as it gets: `ÆṪ` is the built-in totient function and `¡` applies this function as many times as the second argument.

Answer (score 2):

## J, <s>6</s> 4 bytes

```
5&p:
```

Straight-forward approach. Nests the totient function *n* times on an initial value of *x*.

### Usage

```
   f =: 5&p:
   5 f 100
2
```

### Explanation

Normally, `5&p:` is a monad that computes the totient of its argument. However, when used dyadically, it nests itself on an initial value of its LHS according to the number of times on its RHS.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>49</s> <s>46</s> <s>44</s> 40 bytes

Thanks @xnor for another again named solution:

```
x%0=x
x%n=sum[1|1<-gcd x<$>[1..x]]%(n-1)
```

Old version:

The following is an unnamed pointless function that takes two arguments: (Thanks @Lynn for another two bytes!)

```
(!!).iterate(\y->sum[1|t<-[1..y],gcd y t<2])
```

To use it, you can e.g. assign it a name (`f=(!!).(...`) and then call it via `f 10 1` (as an example for the first test case).

Explanation: The lambda function `(\y->sum[1|t<-[1..y],gcd y t<2])` is the totient function. `iterate f x` produces an infinite list `[x,f(x),f(f(x)),f(f(f(x))),...]` and `!!` is just for accessing this list at a specific index.

Older version:

```
x#n=(iterate(\y->sum[1|t<-[1..y],gcd y t<2])x)!!n
```

Usage e.g. for the first test case: `10#1`.

Comment: It's shorter to recurse than to iterate `x%0=x;x%n=sum[1|t<-[1..x],gcd x t<2]%(n-1)`. The list comp can be done as `[1|1<-gcd x<$>[1..x]]`.

Comment: Ah I always forget about the `<$>`, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 33 bytes

Straightforward iteration:

```
f(n,x)=for(i=1,x,n=eulerphi(n));n
```

Straightforward recursion:

```
f(n,x)=if(x,n,f(eulerphi(n),x-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 20 bytes

```
q~{_mf1|1-{1$\/-}/}*
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cX57X21mMXwxLXsxJFwvLX0vfSo&input=MTAwIDM)

#### How it works

```
q~                    Read and evaluate all input. Pushes x and n.
  {               }*  Repeat n times:
   _mf                  Compute the prime factorization of a copy of x.
      1|1-              Add and remove 1 from the prime factorization.
                        | deduplicates and - handles the edge case 1mf -> [1].
          {     }/      For each remaining prime p:
           1$             Push a copy of x.
             \/           Swap with p and divide, pushing x/p.
               -          Subtract from x, pushing x-x/p.
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Hoon](https://github.com/urbit/urbit), 84 bytes

```
|*((pair) ?~(p q $(p (dec p), q (lent (skim (gulf 1 q) |=(@ =(1 d:(egcd +< q))))))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
|*  (pair)
  ?~  p
    q
  %=  $
    p  (dec p)
    q  (lent (skim (gulf 1 q) |=(@ =(1 d:(egcd +< q)))))
  ==
```

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 36 bytes

```julia
n\x=n>0?~-n\sum(k->gcd(k,x)<2,1:x):x
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=blx4PW4-MD9-LW5cc3VtKGstPmdjZChrLHgpPDIsMTp4KTp4Cgpmb3IgKG4seCkgaW4gKCAoMSwxMCksICgyLDEwKSwgKDMsMTApLCAoMSwgMTAwKSwgKDIsIDEwMCksICgzLCAxMDApLCAoNCwgMTAwKSwgKDUsIDEwMCksICg2LCAxMDApICkKICAgIEBwcmludGYoIiUxZCAlM2QgJTJkXG4iLCBuLCB4LCBuXHgpCmVuZA&input=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>47 45 44 43 42 41</s>  39 bytes

```perl6
{($^x,{+(^$^x .grep: {$_ gcd$x==1})}...*)[$^n]}
{($^x,{+(^$^x Xgcd $x).grep: *==1}...*)[$^n]}
{($^x,{+grep *==1,(^$^x Xgcd $x)}...*)[$^n]}
{($^x,{+grep *==1,(^$^x Xgcd$x)}...*)[$^n]}
{($^x,{+grep 2>*,(^$^x Xgcd$x)}...*)[$^n]}
{($^x,{+grep 2>*,(^$_ Xgcd$_)}...*)[$^n]}
{($^x,{sum 2 X>(^$_ Xgcd$_)}...*)[$^n]}
```

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{ # parameters are $n,$x ( declared as placeholder parameters )
  (

    $^x, # seed sequence generator with second argument

    { # parameter is $_
      sum
        2
        X[>] # crossed compared using &infix«>»
        (
          0 ..^ $_ # from 0 up to and excluding the parameter
          X[gcd]   # cross apply &infix:<gcd> with:
          $_       # the parameter
        )
    }

    ...  # keep applying that block

    *    # forever

  )[ $^n ] # grab the one at the index indicated by the first argument
}
```

#### Test:

```perl6
use v6.c;
use Test;

my @tests = (
  (1, 10) =>  4,
  (2, 10) =>  2,
  (3, 10) =>  1,
  (1,100) => 40,
  (2,100) => 16,
  (3,100) =>  8,
  (4,100) =>  4,
  (5,100) =>  2,
  (6,100) =>  1,
);

plan +@tests;

my &repeated-totient = {($^x,{sum 2 X>(^$_ Xgcd$_)}...*)[$^n]}

for @tests -> $_ ( :key(@input), :value($expected) ) {
  is repeated-totient(|@input), $expected, .gist
}
```

```
1..9
ok 1 - (1 10) => 4
ok 2 - (2 10) => 2
ok 3 - (3 10) => 1
ok 4 - (1 100) => 40
ok 5 - (2 100) => 16
ok 6 - (3 100) => 8
ok 7 - (4 100) => 4
ok 8 - (5 100) => 2
ok 9 - (6 100) => 1
```

Comment: So just to confirm... I shouldn't have to cite PPCG in my production Perl?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Please tell me that you aren't going to use this in production. Also this is [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), usually Perl means [Perl 5](http://perl.org). I would probably use `sub φ ( Int \n ) { sum ^n .race.map: -> \k { k gcd n == 1  } }` `say φ 36 # 12` ( I'm sure there is a better algorithm though )

Comment: I was joking. I can't read or comprehend Perl.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Why not? [Perl 6 is easier to read and comprehend than Python](http://perl6.party/post/Python-is-The-New-Write-Only-Linenoise-Language)

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript, 88 <s>95</s>

```
g=(a,b)=>b?g(b,a%b):a==1
t=(x,n=x,o=0)=>n?t(x,--n,o+g(x,n)):o
f=(n,x)=>n?f(n-1,t(x)):x
```

The first function returns true/false if the greatest commom divisor is 1. The second function calculates the *totient*. The third function is a simple recursion to do the totient n times.

I took this idea from the wikipedia link:

> It can be defined more formally as the number of integers k in the range 1 ≤ k ≤ n for which the greatest common divisor gcd(n, k) = 1;